# Working example of latest android facebook sdk login

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, authentication

I am working on custom facebook login button, I found that there is little source (especially working code example) about the latest facebook android sdk. I spent all day but still the code is not working. I wonder if there is any project example or your project code of:

1. facebook login:
2. share session to other activity/fragment (so I can check the login / logout status in everywhere of the app)
3. post to wall
4. logout

Here are my code, but it actually return non-login status even I am logined

Login:

```
public class Login {
    private final static String TAG = "FaceBookLogin";
    public Context ctx;
    public Session fb_session;

    public Login(Context _ctx) {
        ctx = _ctx;
        Settings.addLoggingBehavior(LoggingBehavior.INCLUDE_ACCESS_TOKENS);
        fb_session = Session.getActiveSession();

        if(fb_session == null)                   
            fb_session = Session.openActiveSessionFromCache(ctx);
    }

    public void checkLogin() {
        printHashKey();
        if (fb_session != null && fb_session.isOpened()) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Facebook Login State");
        } else {
            if (fb_session == null)
                fb_session = new Session(ctx);

            Session.setActiveSession(fb_session);
            ConnectToFacebook();
            Log.i(TAG, "Facebook Not login State");
        }
    }

    public void printHashKey() {

        try {
            PackageInfo info = ctx.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("com.project.hkseven",
                    PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
            for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
                MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
                md.update(signature.toByteArray());
                Log.d(TAG,
                        Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
            }
        } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
              Log.d(TAG,""+e);
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
              Log.d(TAG,""+e);
        }

    }

    private void ConnectToFacebook() {
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();

        if(session == null)                   
            session = Session.openActiveSessionFromCache(ctx);

        if (!session.isOpened() && !session.isClosed()) {
            Log.i(TAG, "ConnectToFacebook if");
            OpenRequest newSession = new Session.OpenRequest((Activity) ctx);
            newSession.setCallback(callback);
            session.openForRead(newSession);
            try {
                Session.OpenRequest request = new Session.OpenRequest((Activity) ctx);
                request.setPermissions(Arrays.asList("email","publish_stream","publish_actions"));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d(TAG,""+e);
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            Log.i(TAG, "ConnectToFacebook else");
            Session.openActiveSession((Activity) ctx, true, callback);
        }
    }

    private Session.StatusCallback callback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
        public void call(final Session session, final SessionState state,
                final Exception exception) {
            Log.d(TAG,"callback" + state);
            onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);
        }
    };

    private void onSessionStateChange(final Session session,
            SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        Log.i(TAG, "state change");
        if (session != null && session.isOpened()) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Change to Facebook Login");
        }
    }
}
```

Any kind of help is appreciate , thanks for kindly help

Comment: I have seen one example for login with facebook you can find it here : http://www.demoadda.com/demo/android/login-with-facebook_108

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all install latest sdk and do something like this:

> Under ~\FaceBook-Sdk\facebook-android-sdk-3.5.2\samples.

You will find the samples of whatever you have posted. But may be It will not work. So what you have to do to make it run is:

Make application on Facebook side. Get your fb_api_key from there and put in the project you get from samples.

Comment: Thanks for your help , actually I had go through it before. I looked into SessionLoginSample but that is not so easy to understand and it provide some non-essential code in it. I think I am going to read the hellofacebook one.

Comment: I am looking for some tutorial like this: http://polamreddyn.blogspot.in/2013/12/android-facebook-login-using-facebook.html . Unfortunatelly this example is not working

Comment: I prefer you to first go for Session Login sample then Hellofaebook.

Comment: This is also good tutorial but It is from old sdk: Check it out if you like to: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-facebook-connect-tutorial/

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am customzing the Session Login sample and hope it work with the hellosimple for publishing message

Answer (score 30):

See this example, it is using Latest Facebook SDK and cover basic login + sharing.

Now do the following changes to your application manifest file. Put the following code before  tag. Make sure you are using your own AppID obtained from Facebook developer console.

```
<activity android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />
<meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
                android:value="@string/app_id" />
```

Your Activity Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:facebook="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="20dp" >

    <com.facebook.widget.LoginButton
        android:id="@+id/fb_login_button"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        facebook:confirm_logout="false"
        facebook:fetch_user_info="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/user_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/update_status"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/update_status" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/post_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/post_image" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Activity Java class

```
package com.domain.yourapp;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.facebook.Request;
import com.facebook.Response;
import com.facebook.Session;
import com.facebook.SessionState;
import com.facebook.UiLifecycleHelper;
import com.facebook.model.GraphUser;
import com.facebook.widget.LoginButton;
import com.facebook.widget.LoginButton.UserInfoChangedCallback;

public class FBActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private LoginButton loginBtn;
    private Button postImageBtn;
    private Button updateStatusBtn;

    private TextView userName;

    private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;

    private static final List<String> PERMISSIONS = Arrays.asList("publish_actions");

    private static String message = "Sample status posted from android app";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(this, statusCallback);
        uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_facebook);

        userName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.user_name);
        loginBtn = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.fb_login_button);
        loginBtn.setUserInfoChangedCallback(new UserInfoChangedCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onUserInfoFetched(GraphUser user) {
                if (user != null) {
                    userName.setText("Hello, " + user.getName());
                } else {
                    userName.setText("You are not logged");
                }
            }
        });

        postImageBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.post_image);
        postImageBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                postImage();
            }
        });

        updateStatusBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.update_status);
        updateStatusBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });

        buttonsEnabled(false);
    }

    private Session.StatusCallback statusCallback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state,
                Exception exception) {
            if (state.isOpened()) {
                buttonsEnabled(true);
                Log.d("FacebookSampleActivity", "Facebook session opened");
            } else if (state.isClosed()) {
                buttonsEnabled(false);
                Log.d("FacebookSampleActivity", "Facebook session closed");
            }
        }
    };

    public void buttonsEnabled(boolean isEnabled) {
        postImageBtn.setEnabled(isEnabled);
        updateStatusBtn.setEnabled(isEnabled);
    }

    public void postImage() {
        if (checkPermissions()) {
            Bitmap img = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                    R.drawable.ic_launcher);
            Request uploadRequest = Request.newUploadPhotoRequest(
                    Session.getActiveSession(), img, new Request.Callback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                            Toast.makeText(FBActivity.this,
                                    "Photo uploaded successfully",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    });
            uploadRequest.executeAsync();
        } else {
            requestPermissions();
        }
    }

    public void postStatusMessage() {
        if (checkPermissions()) {
            Request request = Request.newStatusUpdateRequest(
                    Session.getActiveSession(), message,
                    new Request.Callback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                            if (response.getError() == null)
                                Toast.makeText(FBActivity.this,
                                        "Status updated successfully",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    });
            request.executeAsync();
        } else {
            requestPermissions();
        }
    }

    public boolean checkPermissions() {
        Session s = Session.getActiveSession();
        if (s != null) {
            return s.getPermissions().contains("publish_actions");
        } else
            return false;
    }

    public void requestPermissions() {
        Session s = Session.getActiveSession();
        if (s != null)
            s.requestNewPublishPermissions(new Session.NewPermissionsRequest(
                    this, PERMISSIONS));
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        uiHelper.onResume();
        buttonsEnabled(Session.getActiveSession().isOpened());
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        uiHelper.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        uiHelper.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedState);
        uiHelper.onSaveInstanceState(savedState);
    }

}
```

This is complete code, which provides login, status update, image update to the point.

For detail see following link.
http://javatechig.com/android/using-facebook-sdk-in-android-example

Comment: It's link only answer, you must include essential part from the original source because link might be broken or may no longer exist in future.

Comment: @PareshMayani Please, see my above updated post.

Comment: @FaisalBasra bhaie thumbs up for you...!

Comment: Actually I dont find anyway for importing facebook jars. Do you know  about using jar file with gradle? do you have any code for gradle, auto-import? I m using android studio and I need jar file or gradle code.

Comment: What editor are you using?

Comment: Its giving null value for Email in case of native app is installed in device

Comment: could you post the code for the manifest file please?

Comment: @Faisal Bastra: You forgot to call postStatusMessage() inside the updateStatusBtn click listener.

Comment: Nice answer! Helped a lot

Comment: Not working anymore: there is no com.facebook.widget.LoginButton.UserInfoChangedCallback in the latest SDK.

Comment: @pipacs I see you did not accept the answer and added that the example in the link provided stopped working. How did you resolve the matter?

Comment: @Faisal Basra does the link provided work, is the code up-to-date?

Comment: Which Android Facebook SDK version you use in this answer?