# Facebook login: nothing happens after I allow app to access the information

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, facebook-login

I am trying to implement **Facebook Login for Android** using these documentation. I am done with initial app configuration and UI changes. I have a login button.

```
<com.facebook.widget.LoginButton
    android:id="@+id/authButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
/>
```

Things are as expected until I click this button. When I click it the application closes and it goes back to Facebook authentication page.

I allow it access my information there. And then nothing happens. The page gets closed and application is already closed.

- Why is my application closing?
- Where can I catch the response back from authentication page?

Comment: post your code please

Comment: there is no code beyond this. that is what i want to know. where to catch the response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a lot of work behind connecting with Facebook.
create it According to this guide https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/login-with-facebook/v2.2

As for your question, this is the part code where you catch the response

```
private Session.StatusCallback statusCallback = 
new SessionStatusCallback();
...
private void onClickLogin() {
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (!session.isOpened() && !session.isClosed()) {
        session.openForRead(new Session.OpenRequest(this)
           .setPermissions(Arrays.asList("public_profile"))
           .setCallback(statusCallback));
    } else {
        Session.openActiveSession(getActivity(), this, true, statusCallback);
    }
}
...
private class SessionStatusCallback implements Session.StatusCallback {
    @Override
    public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        // Respond to session state changes, ex: updating the view
    }
}
```

Comment: ok thankyou, i will try this in a while. I also find [this tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-facebook-connect-tutorial/) but it is dated from 2012. can you please tell is it applicable?

Comment: i know this tutorial it have a lot of deprecated functions.
but you can start with it just for learning the basics

Comment: ok, i am accepting you answer. just one last thing it would be great if you could point me to an updated tutorial written like the above one. the official document is too confusing for me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21634138/working-example-of-latest-android-facebook-sdk-login

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_facebook_integration.htm

http://programmerguru.com/android-tutorial/how-to-implement-facebook-login-in-android-applications/

You can contact me if you do not get along. maorhadad@gmail.com